# I'm getting FileNotFoundException while running a war

Tags: java, spring

Here is a code line, which I use to access xml file.

```
Contacts contactsEntity = (Contacts) um.unmarshal(new FileReader(new File(classLoader.getResource("Contacts.xml").getFile())));
```

Here is what I get while running a war:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.50\webapps\pb\WEB-INF\lib\phonebook-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!\Contacts.xml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

P.S. It is 100% not an issue with file access, because I made a simple project which generates JAXB classes, unmarshals the same xml from resources folder and everything works fine.

Here is a structure of project:

[image]

Comment: It is a problem with file access because it isn't a file. It is a resource from inside a jar file which cannot be read as a file.

Comment: and how can I deal with it?

Comment: Read it as an input stream not a file.

Comment: @M.Deinum It can be read as a File using Spring's ClassPathResource.

Comment: No it cannot as it isn't a file and that will also fail at runtime (when deployed as a war).

Comment: But I've used it many times by now, and it worked when deployed as war on a Tomcat?

Comment: It might work if your war gets unpacked if that doesn't happen it won't work. Reading things as a file will only work if it actually exists as a file on the file system (and hence it will work when a war gets unpacked prior to deployment by your app server).

Comment: Indeed. I don't know about other servlet containers, but Tomcat does unpack the war.

Comment: The same would fail if using Spring Boot and an embedded container as that doesn't unpack. Hence to be safe you are better to use an inputstream instead of a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've tagged [spring](/questions/tagged/spring), so I assume you can use it.

Does your war get unpacked after deployment (e.g. by Tomcat)?

## If yes,

Use `ClassPathResource#getFile()`

Your problem is the String that gets returned by `getFile()`. It contains an exclamation mark (`!`) and a `file:` protocol. You could handle all that yourself and implement your own solution for this, but this would be reinventing the wheel.

Fortunately, Spring has a `org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource`. To get the file, simple write `new ClassPathResource("filename").getFile();` In your case, you need to replace

```
Contacts contactsEntity = (Contacts) um.unmarshal(new FileReader(new File(classLoader.getResource("Contacts.xml").getFile())));
```

with

```
Contacts contactsEntity = (Contacts) um.unmarshal(new FileReader(new ClassPathResource("Contacts.xml").getFile()));
```

Now your program should also work when it's deployed and unpacked.

## If no (recommended, use this if you're not sure),

You have to use an `InputStream`, as the resource doesn't exist as a file on the filesystem, but is rather packed inside of an archive.

This should work:

```
Contacts contactsEntity = (Contacts) um.unmarshal(new InputStreamReader(new ClassPathResource("Contacts.xml").getInputStream()));
```

(without Spring):

```
Contacts contactsEntity = (Contacts) um.unmarshal(new InputStreamReader(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("Contacts.xml")));
```

Comment: Now I get this: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Contacts.xml] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/D:/apache-tomcat-8.0.50/webapps/pb/WEB-INF/lib/phonebook-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/Contacts.xml`

Comment: Okay.. I guess you need to read it as an InputStream as M. Deinum suggested.

Comment: Thanks. It finally works with this line of code: `Contacts contactsEntity = (Contacts) um.unmarshal(new InputStreamReader(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("Contacts.xml")));`

Comment: thank you thank you, your answer helped me allot after two days of search