# how to get file path in war file to deploy on tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, war

I have test.json file that I am using in my project and its works fine but when I extract the project to war file to deploy on tomcat I get error the file path not found is there a way to get the correct file path or to fix it

```
 new FileInputStream("src/main/java/com/example/project/test.json");
```

Comment: use `/src/....` absolute path to reach the test.json file.  Also this is not a very correct path to keep files other than .java. You can use the resources folder. Or something like WEB-INF/lib. The  try to read from there. You can use path redirection from your current folder like `../../` to reach the actual file. If not working then paste a screen shot of your project structure which you are exporting to WAR. Include the package also to show where is your java file and where is ur json file.

Comment: hi my structure is the same of maven project structure if you can help me where to put the test.json file and how to reache it in the maven project and in the war project

Comment: this answer worked for me [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445042/im-getting-filenotfoundexception-while-running-a-war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445042/im-getting-filenotfoundexception-while-running-a-war)